# How to get font size to show up in a cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

i've been looking everywhere for solution.

I want to create an app script on Google Sheets that creates a custom formula to show what font size text a cell contains.

I found Google has a function "[getFontSize](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-style#getfontsize)", but no luck in getting it to work:

```html
function FONTSIZE(range) {
  return getFontSize(Number)
}
```

Any help would be appreciated as i am a script app noob!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the font size.
- From your showing script, you might want to achieve this as a custom function.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function FONTSIZE(range) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(range).getFontSizes();
}
```

- In this case, please put a custom function like `=FONTSIZE("A1")` and `=FONTSIZE("A1:C3")` in a cell. By this, the font size of the cell "A1" is returned.

#### Note:

- When I saw your showing document of the URL, it seems that it is for Google Slides. If you want to use this with Google Spreadsheet, please use [`getFontSize()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getfontsize) and/or [`getFontSizes()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getfontsizes).

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [getFontSizes()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getfontsizes)

Comment: This was exactly what i needed. Thank you!

In the end i used =FONTSIZE("B:B") to get all of values for a total column, then i was able to filtered in order of size.

Comment: @Rhys Davies Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.